# What does the error 32111 in the Auction house mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was trying to buyout an item on the Auction house and it said error 32111.  What does this mean?  ( Now I have a logged error of it in my completed menu )

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: @z- Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't find official confirmation, I believe this error indicates that you attempted to buy something that no longer exists.  This generally means that someone else purchased the item in question while you were browsing.

You'll get this error often if you try to buy popular/in demand commodity items (gems, crafting materials, etc), especially when the prices are far below market.  The quantity of people shopping means that there are lots of buyers watching item prices and snapping up good deals.

Although the game will temporarily take your money when this error occurs, I've found that shortly afterwards it shows up on the "Completed" tab as a "Failed" purchase.  In some cases I was able to speed up the refund process by entering and then leaving a game session.

Comment: What's worse than this error is when you try to buyout a commodity item (ie, a gem) at a low price, and the trade is confirmed, but *not for the price you saw in the buyout window!*