# What does "Purchase Refund" mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

In my Completed tab, I had a Purchase Refund.  I did not get a [failed purchase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67866/what-does-the-error-32111-in-the-auction-house-mean).  Where did this come from?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get purchase refunds for two reasons:

1. If you're buying a commodity, and the auction house found someone had posted a cheaper stack up there compared to what you had looked like paying.
2. Someone else purchased the item you wanted to purchase, so the auction house refunded the amount for the items that you did not receive.

Basically, these are due to trades made between the time you saw the price of whatever you bought in the AH and when you clicked the buyout button.  Since the AH does not automatically refresh, there could be a significant difference between what you can see and what's available (though you can get a different "That item is already bought" error depending on the timing).

Comment: More specifically, #2 is when you do not successfully purchase the quantity you were bidding on.  The number in the refund is the amount you *did* purchase.